# "That ... is" or "that ... be"

Tags: conjugation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why have the subjunctive and indicative converged in Modern English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/why-have-the-subjunctive-and-indicative-converged-in-modern-english)

Simple question, should you say "what matters most is **that** the merger **is** successful"

or: "what matters most is **that** the merger **be** successful"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*What matters most is that the merger **be** successful* sounds better to me. The subjunctive mood shows that the merger hasn't happened yet and you are expressing a wish for it to be successful.

Comment: Would you extend that to all persons? 'What matters most is that I be successful', for example.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't sound odd to me. It isn't a real situation, therefore the indicative doesn't express the wish as clearly as the subjunctive, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Irene. As Barrie indicated, if this structure is mostly found in American English, then this is the one I am going with. I am French, but the English I speak is American :)

Answer (score 8):

It's not really a matter of 'should'. In *What matters most is that the merger is successful*, *is* is indicative. In *What matters most is that the merger be successful*, *be* is subjunctive. This form of subjunctive seems to be found more in American English than in British English, where it creates a formal and rather prissy tone. An alternative that might be found in British English is *What matters most is that the merger should be successful.*

Comment: The same alternative is indeed perfectly fine in American English.