# Future tense in conditional clauses

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, conditionals, future, conditional-future

All the textbooks I have ever come across during the course of my studying English emphasize that future tense should not be used in conditional clauses.

For example,

> If it rains in the evening, we will not go for a walk. (<strike>if it will rain in the evening...</strike>)
>
> We decided to go for a walk if it didn't rain in the evening. (<strike>...if it wouldn't rain in the evening)</strike>

However, in the following sentence I'm really inclined to use the future tense.

> Don't implement this feature if it will significantly increase the complexity of the user interface.

According to all the rules I know of, the future tense is illegal here. However, my gut feeling tells me that the sentence is correct. If I am wrong, the question ends here. Otherwise please read on. I find the last example different from my first two because:

- In the first examples we must wait and see if the condition is true, and then make a decision accordingly, whereas in the last example, we must actually analyze/predict/forecast the future in order to make the decision in the present.
- <sub>(might be irrelevant)</sub> In my first language - Armenian - where we have a special mood for conditions, the translation of the third sentence actually uses indicative, whereas the first two use that special mood (the conditional mood, as it were).

Since the second would-be principle is easier for me to experiment with, I noticed that every time a condition uses the indicative mood in my language, I'm inclined to use the future tense in English. As another example:

> I will give you the money if it will make you happier.

Am I imagining things or are my examples of the future tense in the conditional clause valid? If they are valid, what rule would you suggest to distinguish the cases when it's OK?  (I do realize that translating a sentence to another language and analyzing the translation doesn't really count as a rule).

Comment: At first glance, your intuitive choice seems misplaced as far as the English language is concerned. As in Armenian, so it is in at least some other languages, but not in English I am afraid. By the very sound of it (possibly because it's atypical), the future tense stands out as odd. Let's see what theoretical explanations the others may provide.

Comment: Related: [Why have the subjunctive and indicative converged in modern English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/why-have-the-subjunctive-and-indicative-converged-in-modern-english)

Comment: @Kitḫ: I haven't looked at the reference, but Armen's questions don't concern the subjunctive.

Comment: [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from ***“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”,*** Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press,  doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Comment: For what it's worth, this native English speaker thinks that both of your sentences "Don't implement this feature if it will significantly increase the complexity of the user interface." and "I will give you the money if it will make you happier." sound perfectly fine and natural.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the difference between the two types of examples that you've exhibited is the relative placement in time of the action in the "if" clause, and the action in the other clause.

- If it rains in the evening, we won't go for a walk - here, the event of raining occurs BEFORE the decision about whether to go for a walk.
- My teeth will rot if I eat too much sugar - presumably, I'll be eating the sugar BEFORE my teeth rot.
- If it will significantly increase complexity, don't implement this feature - here, the increasing of complexity occurs AFTER the implementation of the feature.
- I will give you money if it will make you happier - here, you becoming happier occurs AFTER I give you the money.

In all the cases where the "if" part happens first chronologically, we use the present tense.  In the cases where the "if" part happens second, we use the future tense.  However, because sentences of the first type are far more common than sentences in the second type, a good rule for learners to adopt is "don't use the future tense with IF".

Comment: And to complicate things further, there are two cases when the "if" part happens second chronologically: the case where it is a consequence of the action in the main clause, and the case where it is simply a prediction of an event. In the second case, I think we have to put it into the future using "going to". In the first case, we can use "will". An example of the second case is "if it's going to rain later, I'll bring my umbrella."

Comment: I just read this sentence from a novel: If you will give me your name I will have a firm brochure mailed to you.  Another example is, ladies and gentlemen, if you will be seated..... I think I heard it in a TV show. So I guess sometimes future tense in if clause conveys a sense of politeness?

Answer (score 13):

In some cases, it is possible to use "will" in "if" sentences to imply

**A) willingness**

> If you'll  just hold the door open for me a moment, I can take this table out to the kitchen.

**B) obstinate persistence**

> If you will keep all the windows shut, of course you'll get headaches

**C) if the "if" action is after the main action**, will (or an equivalent expression indicating the Future) is used in the if clause

> If aspirins will cure it, I'll  take a couple tonight.

Please check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence#cite_note-lingua_org_uk_eqa-0) and [lingua.org](http://www.lingua.org.uk/eq&a.html) and [a page from Berkeley](http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/%7Ekay/bcg/lec07.html)

**Edit 1** Per @Brett Reynolds and @Peter Shor

As far as I can see,  "will"  may first impose a change in the order of actions and then "both "will" and "order of action"  contribute to meaning. The contribution depends on context and may imply "a willingness", "a persistence" "a wish", "a prediction" e.t.c.  Please compare:

> I will give  money if you will do it.
>
> I will give money if you do it.

Comment: Good points. Is it a coincidence that your examples all start with the condition?

Comment: I'm afraid, c) is wrong. The order has nothing to do with it. Consider, **if it will rain later, I'll bring my umbrella.*

Comment: @Brett: the order certainly has something to do with the tense you use. You shouldn't say "if it rains later, I'll bring my umbrella". You'd say "if it's going to rain later", the other future verb construction in English.

Comment: I believe that the rule for case c) is that when the "if" clause is a prediction, you must use "going to", but when the "if" clause is a consequence of the action in the main clause, you can use "will"

Comment: Yes, the problem is with the meaning of *will,* not with the order in which things happen.

Comment: Both the order and the meaning of *will* play a role here.

Comment: What's the evidence?

Comment: @Brett Reynolds, please see my edit.

Comment: @Brett Reynolds, Consider the sentence "I will pay for the repairs if they will keep the building from falling down in the next earthquake." Here you need the *will* because the next earthquake is in the future, while in a sentence like "I will pay for the repairs if they (will) make the building safer", the *will* is optional. If you leave out the *will* in the first sentence, it sounds like you are refusing to pay for them until after the next earthquake.

Comment: The point is that you don't need both meaning and sequence to explain this. Meaning will do.

Comment: @Brett: that's true, but it still feels to me like that *will* signifies the future.

Comment: @BrettReynolds, why is "If it will rain later, I'll bring my umbrella" ungrammatical? And do you think it's ungrammatical in all contexts, or does a sentence like this work: "If -- as the weather reports said today morning -- it will rain later, I'll bring my umbrella"?

Comment: @Brett Reynolds I will stop drinking if it will save my marriage. or I will stop drinking if it saves my marriage. I think you won't disagree that only the first one makes sense.

Comment: @user1425 actually, I would disagree. The second clause "if it saves my marriage" is futurate, and perfectly common.

Comment: @Brett Reynolds I never said it wasn't futurate. They all are. The point is which follows which. You have to quit drinking FIRST. But you suggest quitting drinking after quitting drinking saves your marriage. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: @user1425 Sorry for misunderstanding you! Still, though, it's fine for me. I don't get any ordering effect. That is, just because the "if" clause is placed first doesn't mean it occurs first.

Comment: @Brett Reynolds Of course, it's not because of the fact that the if clause is placed first. It can be placed second with the same effect. The decisive point is that "if" clause contains "will".

Comment: @user1425, I'm afraid I don't get that interpretation.

Answer (score 8):

The first thing to say is that English has no future tense. (This sometimes comes as a surprise.) There are, however, various ways of expressing the future and *will* + the plain form of the main verb is one of them.

It’s true that that construction is not found in the *if* clause of conditional sentences such as your first example (‘If it rains in the evening . . .’). However, there are occasions when it is used, particularly where *will* expresses volition, as in ‘If you will follow me, I’ll take you to your table.’ That could be expressed as ‘If you follow me, . . .’, but the construction with *will* adds a degree of politeness.  Your example ‘I will give you the money if it will make you happier’ is similar. That could also be expressed as ‘. . . if it makes you happier’, but here the *will* construction softens what might otherwise be a harsh remark. It assumes (or, for the sake of kindness, appears to assume) a greater probability that the condition will be met.

Much the same applies in your example ‘Don't implement this feature if it will significantly increase the complexity of the user interface.’ It, too, could be written with ‘. . . if it significantly increases . . .’ By using the *will* construction, however, the writer to some extent prejudges the chance that the complexity of the interface will be increased if the instruction is ignored.

The authors of the ‘Cambridge Grammar of English' sum up these constructions when they write:

> Modal verbs (most typically *will* or *would*) may occur in
>   conditional clauses if they have a meaning of willingness or
>   prediction, or where it is important to mark politeness.

Comment: I think CGE is mistaken when it allows modals for prediction in *if* clauses. It's actually disastrously chalk full of errors. http://english-jack.blogspot.com/2008/03/more-muddled-grammar.html

Comment: @BrettReynolds, can you explicate "chalk full"?

Comment: Slip o' the fingers. "Chalk full" should be "chock full" = very full.

Comment: @BrettReynolds: I hadn’t previously seen the Huddleston review, but his criticisms must of course be taken seriously. I don’t use it all that much, partly because I haven’t found it particularly user-friendly, and that applies not only to the index. For the case in hand, the willingness and politeness points hold, even if the prediction one doesn’t. But we still have to explain to Armen how ‘if it will significantly increase’ differs from ‘if it significantly increases’.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct and the "rule" is the problem. The misunderstanding arises partially, at least, from the idea English even has a future tense. [It doesn't](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=897). What it does have, however, is modal auxiliary verbs like *will, may,* and *can,* which typically have future time reference.

In fact, the problem only resides with certain modals (mainly *will, may, might,* and *could*) when they are used to express probability. Thus, *it could rain tomorrow* doesn't work as **if it could rain tomorrow,* but *you could help me tomorrow, couldn't you* easily becomes *if you could help me tomorrow* because *could* here is denoting ability or willingness rather than probability. Note that this also holds true for present and past time as well as future time.

In *if it will make you happier,* the speaker is not predicting that it will make you happier. That is taken for granted. That's why you can respond "It does/will. It makes/will make me happier."

Similarly, *if it will significantly increase the complexity of the user interface* does not involve a prediction. Unlike in the case of rain, where it is simply impossible for anybody to know, here it is merely unknown to the person giving the advice, but it is taken for granted that the receiver of that advice knows the effect that "it" will have.

This also, by the way, explains why the so-called "going-to future" isn't a problem. I discuss this point [here](http://english-jack.blogspot.com/2007/09/if-they-will-only-listen.html).

Comment: Some explanations for the multiple down votes would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I found your explanation written very confusingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *will* in the *if-clause* if you are focused on the result. Consider:

1. I will give you the money if it will make you happier.
2. I will give you the money if you ask nicely.

In sentence one the **result** of giving is making your friend happy. In sentence two the **condition** of giving is that your friend asks nicely.

Comment: But what is the difference between 'I will give you the money if it will make you happier' and 'I will give you the money if it makes you happier'?

Comment: My post was an attempt to give a simplistic explanation of when it is possible to break what the OP thought was a rule that *if clauses* cannot contain *will*. But as your question makes clear, the *will* is not mandatory in result clauses. It could be that *I will give you the money if it makes you happier* implies that the being happier will occur now, on me telling you this. And *I will give you the money if it will make you happier* implies the being happier will occur when you receive the money. But I'm not ready to go to the barricades in support of this suggestion.

Answer (score -3):

In conditional sentences that are realistic, always use the present tense in the "if" part of the sentence and the future in the other part, so:

> If it makes you happier, I will give you the money.

or

> I will give you the money, if it makes you happier.

In unrealistic sentences, use the past tense in the "if" part of the sentence and *would/could/might/should* + verb in the other part, so:

> If I were rich, I would buy a brand new car.

or

> I would buy a brand new car, if I were rich.

In impossible situations (in the past, so no longer possible), use past perfect in the "if" part and *could have/might have/would have* + past participle in the other part, so:

> If I had known, I would have helped you.

or

> I would have helped you, if I had known.

This way of explaining the conditional sentences has been helpful for my students.

Comment: This isn't what I was asking