# When is "will" used in an "if" clause?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditionals, sentence-patterns, subjunctive-mood, will-be-going

Given the following sentences that use *will* in the *if* clause (which is seldom with if-clauses and therefore, I'm not sure they all are even grammatical or not).

> - If you **will/would** kindly lend me your book, I will be thankful to you.
> - If you **will not/would** not mind lending me your book, I will be thankful to you.
> - If you **will/would** wait for a while, I will check it for you.

---

> - If you will use it, you can have it
> - If you will not arrive before six o'clock, I cannot meet you.

What if the last sentence is modified as follows?

> If you will not **be arriving** before six o'clock, I cannot meet you.

Once upon a time, it was found in a grammar book.

---

> If the play will not be finished until ten o'clock, I will have to spend the night at your place.

Can the following version of this sentence have a different meaning (or no meaning at all — a wrong sense)?

> If the play is not **going to be finished** until ten o'clock, I will have to spend the night at your place.

After all, the question is when is *will* used in if-clauses as the title implies?

---

Moreover, both the following sentences appear to indicate a probable condition.

> - If he came, I **should** help him.
> - If he came, I **would** help him.

Using *should* and *would* interchangeably in such contexts implies a significant difference in meaning?

Comment: Related: [Future tense in conditional clauses](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/future-tense-in-conditional-clauses)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seem to be several questions here. I’ll answer the one in the title.

I believe foreign learners are taught, at least at the lower levels, that an *if* clause cannot contain the modal verb *will* . This is good advice as far as it goes. We have to say *If you run, you will catch the train* and not *If you will run, you will catch the train*. However . . .

*Will* (*’ll*) and *won’t* may be used in the *if* clause to express the possibility of willingness (or its absence) on the part the person addressed. It can be used as a form of politeness, as in *If you **’ll** come this way, I’ll show you a few samples*. In its negative form it can be a threat, as in *If you **won’t** try harder, I’m not going to help you.*

Answer (score 10):

As I often say, [this topic seems to come up with some frequency here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61308/15299).

The answer lies in the different Deontic 'be willing to (do)' and Epistemic 'be expected to (occur)' senses that *will* has; only the Deontic sense is allowed in *If*-clauses.

Every [modal auxiliary verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) has at least one Epistemic and one Deontic sense, and they often have very different grammar and meaning, especially in hypothetical situations.

Answer (score 0):

To foreign learners, it is important that rules should not be broken, and they are not, even in the case of "If you will come this way, I will show you a few samples."

The rule which says that 'if' is never followed by future tenses holds!

The verb form 'you will come' is not one thing – the Future Simple of 'to come' – but two: the **Present Simple** of the modal auxiliary **'will'**, meaning 'be willing to' **+** the **Bare Infinitive** of the verb '**to come**'.

Et voilà, le tour est joué…