# How to use the phrase “if you will”?

Tags: idioms, deontic-vs-epistemic

Am I using the phrase *if you will* correctly here?

> To be honest, she wasn't much to look at, a plain Jane, **if you will.**

Comment: *If you will* sounds fine to me.  In fact, I frequently use this very construction.

Comment: @Anonym This very *construct*, if you will. :)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/115478/2085).

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is a perfectly normal construction. The OED says in a note against sense 17 of the verb that:

> ***if you will*** is sometimes used parenthetically to qualify a word or phrase: = ‘if you wish it to be so called’, ‘if you choose or prefer to call it so’.

So these all mean the same thing:

- To be honest, she wasn’t much to look at — a plain Jane, **if you will.**
- To be honest, she wasn’t much to look at — a plain Jane, **as they say.**
- To be honest, she wasn’t much to look at — a plain Jane, **as the saying goes.**
- To be honest, she wasn’t much to look at — a plain Jane, **so to speak.**
- To be honest, she wasn’t much to look at — a plain Jane, **as it were.**

You could also use a semicolon there instead of an em dash.  But you really shouldn’t use a comma.

Also, you should understand that this is the [**deontic** sense of *will*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/88251).   That means it’s related to permission, obligation, and so on.  It has nothing whatsoever to do with futurity, and it is not a marker for that here.  It’s like “if you will allow”, but you don’t need to *allow* because *will* already means that.