# Subjunctive mood: were or was?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

Here, I copied a sentence from a book published by Cambridge Press: ''Nusselt number is the ratio of the actual heat transfer to what it would be if there **were** conduction but no convection.''

This may be a simple question for you. But I confused about the ''were'' in the subordinate clause and supposed it should be **was** since conduction is in singular form. Could you please explain this issue?
Thanks for your comments.

Comment: "Were" is OK, though it is 'irrealis' mood, not subjunctive. Irrealis is limited to 1/3 person singular forms (of "be"), as is the case here. You could replace it with the less formal modal preterite "was": "if there **was** conduction but no convection".

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Was" and "were", which is correct in this context? Can a mood be established in a terminating clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87070/was-and-were-which-is-correct-in-this-context-can-a-mood-be-established-in) // [when to use if I was vs if i were](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/when-to-use-if-i-was-vs-if-i-were].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of an "unreal conditional clause".

See:

https://www.grammarly.com/blog/conditional-sentences-was-instead-of-were/

Comment: The problem with websites like 'Grammarly' is that they get many things wrong. For instance in the link you provided, they say that _If I was a rich man, I would make more charitable donations is wrong_. But it isn't wrong -- it's fine. The use of the modal preterite "was" is just less formal than irrealis "were", not grammatically incorrect.