# Could someone explain whether the following sentence is grammatically correct: " If you would have answered your phone, you would know smth.."

Tags: grammar, conditionals

I ran into this sentence while watching a TV show.
Context: One person tried to call another person, but the latter didn't answer. So the first person came to the other and said as mentioned above.

In my understanding it is supposed to be a type of mixed conditional that refering to an unreal past condition (past perfect) and the probable result in the present (present conditional). With this said, the sentence should've been as follows: "If you had answered your phone, you would know..
".

Comment: As a native speaker, this present-after-past-perfect sounds awkward/sloppy, but in an unsurprising way. Yet: _If you had read the textbook, you would know the answers to the test questions_ sounds less so.

Comment: Isn't this "If you had read the textbook, you would have known" the more correct version?

Comment: An answer to a similar question contains this extract from _Practical English Usage_: "Conditional 'would' is sometimes used in both clauses of an if-sentence. This is very informal, and is not usually written. It is common in spoken American English." https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122198/use-of-would-for-subjunctive-phrases