# Present or Past?

Tags: past-tense, subjunctive-mood

In this sentence: "It might be relaxing if you read a book" - why is the verb 'read' in past tense? Why isn't the verb 'read' in past tense with this example: "Why not read a book?"

I'm just trying to figure out when you would use past tense when making suggestions (**why not** *read* a book, **what if** you *read* a book to help you relax, etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: It's an unfortunate example, sine the *written* form of ***to read*** looks the same in past and present tense (it's just that past tense rhymes with ***red***, and present tense with ***reed***). At least with something like ***listen[ed]** to music* we'd be able to see the difference as text. Whatever - for most contexts either tense is fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Actually, that sentence can be *red* either way.  I'm no expert, but it appears to be in the [subjunctive mood](http://www.npr.org/2013/12/13/248195238/does-the-subjunctive-have-a-dark-side).  But you may *reed* it differently if you wish.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I'm no expert either, but I was already pretty sure the ***red*** version here is [subjunctive](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional.htm). And looking at *my* link (yours was too long for me at the moment! :) I suppose I have to accept the ***reed*** version as subjunctive too. Mostly though, I stick to *there are only two tenses - present, and not-present*, in which context obviously a hypothetical ***if*** clause isn't here/now/present. I guess the solution to that riddle is that subjunctive is a *mood*, not a tense (so maybe it depends on how you feel! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - All I know is that thinking about that stuff too much makes me cranky.

Answer (score 1):

It's the English version of the [subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood) mood. In this case, it's the past subjunctive, which expresses a [counterfactual conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional) situation—one that you wish were true but isn't.

In a lot of other languages, it would be much more apparent that you were writing in a different mood, because the verb would be conjugated differently. But that's not really how English rolls.

So the sentence "Why not read a book?" isn't in the past tense because it's not counterfactual; it doesn't refer to any hypothetical, non-existent version of reality.

(References from Wikipedia.)

---

(If you're interested, I found [this earlier question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/why-have-the-subjunctive-and-indicative-converged-in-modern-english) on EL&U, which has some interesting information in the answers on the subject of *why* the subjunctive is so hard to notice in English.)

Comment: I can't see the relevance of *"Why not read a book?" isn't in the past tense*. By the same token, "I might read a book" isn't in the past tense. The entire issue is unnecessarily confused by OP choosing to use an irregular verb in which past, present, *and* subjunctive all have the same written form, but the bottom line is *"It might help if you read a book"* is equally valid with the "present" tense ***reed*** pronunciation. And I'm pretty sure both versions are subjunctive mood, representing hypothetical situations. They're just "the one and only other" tense (not present).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The counterfactual conditional is formed with the past subjunctive. The present version, "It might help if you read a book," is not the subjunctive, although there is such a thing as present subjunctive. Check out the articles I linked.

Comment: A better example might be _It might be relaxing if you took a walk_, There you can see that we really do use the past tense.

Answer (score -1):

In your sentence "It might be relaxing, if you read the book.", the verb "read" is in present tense not in past tense, and if we want to say this in past tense we would say- "It might be relaxing, if you would read the book." It could be said in another way as- It might be relaxing, if you would have read the book. See uses of would in dictionary, you will be more clear about it.

Comment: The structure **if you would read** is wrong. Either you use **I wish/If only + would + base form** when you want the behaviour of someone or something to change.