# Structure with Wish statements about future events: past perfect or past?

Tags: wish-preterite

Could you please explain the difference between these two sentences?

- The weekend has flown by; I wish it wasn't Monday tomorrow.
- The weekend has flown by; I wish it hadn't been Monday tomorrow.

Comment: Hadn't been is past, tomorrow is future. On Tuesday, I can say hadn't been Monday.

Comment: ...and to confuse matters even more, some would say "I wish it _weren't_ Monday tomorrow".

Comment: As it is counterfactual, some would prefer 'The weekend has flown by; I wish it weren't Monday tomorrow'

Comment: The first sentence is fine, though as mentioned, some would say _I wish it weren't_ instead of _I wish it wasn't_. The second sentence, however,  is completely ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is certainly more standard. Traditionally, the word *wish*, in English, took a verb in the subjunctive mood after it. To express something in the future, the past subjunctive was used.

In your example, the *indicative* is used (*wasn't*), rather than the subjunctive (*weren't*). Using the subjunctive, your sentence would read:

> The weekend has flown by; I wish it *weren't* Monday tomorrow.

However, as the subjunctive's use became progressively less (see [this discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/why-have-the-subjunctive-and-indicative-converged-in-modern-english)), the indicative came to be used in it's place progressively more. It thus became common to use the simple past (indicative) to express the future in hypothetical and non-actual situations, as was done in your first example.

In summary, it's more standard to use the past (whether indicative or subjunctive) to express the future after *wish*.

Comment: The question is about "wasn't" versus "hadn't been", not "wasn't" versus "weren't".

Comment: @Barmar I answered the question in the title. Particularly in my final sentence.

Comment: The title is just a brief summary, the actual question is in the text. And if there's a difference, it's the text that matters (and the title should be corrected to reflect it).